# next.js fetch api response.text unable to get it renderend in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, next.js

i made this code to  backup a sbc session border controller

the code work good this is the output off concole.log result.

the problem is the response is a tekst/ini file object
and somehow it not possible to show (RESULT) in my webpage

hopefully anyone can adjust my code

underneath is the code i use

```
/////////////////// api scrip audiocodes
import styles from '/styles/Home.module.css' 

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic password");
  
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  
  
  const response = await fetch("http://10.0.5.26/api/v1/files/ini", requestOptions);
  const result = await response.text();
  
  return {
      props: { result }
  }
  }
  ////////////////   start website
  const Backup = () => {
    
  



return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>
          refresh <a href="index1">{ result }</a>
        </h1>
      
    </div>
  );
} 
export default Backup;
```

```
;**************
;** Ini File **
;**************

;Time & Date: 19/08/2021 15:18:42
;Device Up Time: 52d:3h:43m:21s
;Board: UNIVERGE BX9000
;Board Type: 72
;Serial Number: 9107130
;Software Version: 7.20A.256.721
;DSP Software Version: 5014AE3_R => 723.06
;Board IP Address: 0.0.0.0
;Board Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
;Board Default Gateway: 0.0.0.
;CPU: Cavium Networks Octeon V0.1 @ 500Mhz, total 2 cores, 2 cpus, 1 sockets
;Cores mapping:
;core #0, on cpu #0, on socket #0
;core #1, on cpu #1, on socket #0
;Memory: 512 MB
;Flash size: 64 MB
;Num of DSP Cores: 3
;Num of physical LAN ports: 12
;Client defaults file is being used (file length=1573)
;;;Key features:;Board Type: 72 ;IP Media: VXML ;DATA features: FireWall&VPN ;PSTN Protocols: ISDN IUA=2 CAS ;Security: IPSEC MediaEncryption StrongEncryption EncryptControlProtocol ;Channel Type: RTP DspCh=150 ;HA ;Coders: G723 G729 GSM-FR G727 G722 ;DSP Voice features: IpmDetector ;Control Protocols: MSFT FEU=50 SIP SBC=25 ;Default features:;Coders: G711 G726;

;-----  HW components -----
;
; Slot # : Module type : # of ports
;----------------------------------------------
;      1 : Empty
;      2 : Empty
;      3 : Empty
;----------------------------------------------
```

screenshots

[![error in next.js][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfRCw.png

this javascript i use in node.js works perfect but somehow i don,t get it to work in next.js

```
///audiocodes api get ini file from sbc
const options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'http://10.0.5.26/api/v1/files/ini',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Basic password'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
  fs.writeFileSync('board.ini', (response.body));
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very common question. Drop the `.then().then()` syntax and go `async/await`.

```
const response = await fetch("http://10.0.5.26/api/v1/files/ini", requestOptions);
const result = await response.text();

return {
    props: { result }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately still have error   Server Error

ReferenceError: result is not defined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

.next\server\pages\test2.js (32:37) @ Backup

  30 | <div>
  31 |   <h1 className={styles.title}>
> 32 |       refresh <a href="index1">{ result.result }</a>
     |                                 ^
  33 |     </h1>
  34 |   
  35 | </div>

Answer (score 0):

problem solved good code is under neath

```
/////////////////// api scrip audiocodes
import styles from '/styles/Home.module.css' 
import Head from 'next/head'
const fs = require('fs');

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic password");
  
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  
  
  const response = await fetch("http://1.1.1.1/api/v1/files/ini", requestOptions);
  const result = await response.text();
 console.log(result);
 fs.writeFileSync('board.ini', (result));
 
  
  return {
      props: { 
        result, 
      }
  }
  }
  ////////////////   start website
  const Backup = ({result}) => {
    
return (
  <div>
      
  <Head>
    <title>Api</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  </Head>
  <h1 className={styles.title}>
      <a href="">configuration</a>
    </h1>
  

      <p className={styles.description}>
      Description:{' '}
      <code className={styles.code}>backup wordt gemaakt</code>
    </p>

</div>
  );
} 
export default Backup;
```